# Есть ли у кого опыт использования Apache Lucene в качестве основного провайдера данных?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

Прикрутили мы значит Apache Lucene к приложению. Используем его для полнотекстового поиска по системе. И тут возник вопрос, а можно ли использовать индекс, созданный Apache Lucene в качестве основного источника данных? Т.е. не ходить в БД за данными, от слова совсем.

Приложение из области "кровавого ынтэрпрайза" - СЭД. Данных становится все больше, выборки становятся все медленнее. Понятно, что можно оптимизировать запросы, оптимизировать саму СУБД. Но ведь Lucene не плохо справляется с задачей быстрого доступа к данным по заданным критериям.

Собственно хотелось бы услышать советы по использованию (или не использованию) Lucene, или аналогичного движка, в качестве основного источника данных приложения.

В общем все сводится к такому вопросу: есть ли смысл загнать данные БД в индекс Lucene, и использовать этот индекс в качестве основного источника данных в приложении? Если так кто-то делает, поделитесь опытом как стоит это делать? Или наоборот, как не стоит этого делать? Какие "грабли" есть на этом пути?

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Уточните, какой у вас основной вопрос, "можно ли использовать индекс, созданный Apache Lucene в качестве основного источника данных?" или "хотелось бы услышать советы по использованию" ? **подсказка, 2ое - оффтопик, ибо слишком размыто*

Comment: Попробую точнее сформулировать. Имеет ли смысл загонять все данные БД в индекс lucene, и использовать его [индекс] как основной источник данных приложения. Если такая вещь имеет смысл, и кто-то так делает, хотелось бы услышать советы на тему как надо и как не надо делать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите уточнения в вопрос (кнопка "править")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть небольшой опыт в похожем проекте и мысли по этому вопросу.
(сам использовал Elastic и Cassandra в связке)

- Один Lucene (или Elastic как обертка над ним) использовать нельзя. Там есть и будут проблемы с доступностью данных (запуск мержа внутри Lucene приведет к огромной деградации производительности поиска, балансировка нод и тд.)
- Сам по себе Lucene нужен для поиска, поэтому его и стоит использовать именно для этой задачи

В целом, такая схема у нас показала свою жизнеспособность с огромным количеством данных. Горизонтальная масштабируемость, простота конфигурации и API и тд.
Принцип работы у нас следующий:

1. Любой поисковый запрос идет в Elastic.
2. Если данных из документа достаточно - то они сразу и возвращаются.
3. Если недостаточно - идем в Cassandra по айди документа.

При этом Cassandra в этой схеме используется как основное хранилище, которое 
   а) вернет данные по ключу очень быстро
   б) поможет восстановить индекс в случае каких-либо проблем.